# The kronecker symbol and factorization of $n=\frac{B^N-1}{B-1}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, factorization, divisors-multiples

Let $n=\frac{B^N-1}{B-1}$.  Assume $n$ is congruent to 3 modulo 4.

We have the following:

1. If $N$ is 1 modulo 4, then $N$ is quadratic residue modulo $n$
   and $-N$ is quadratic non-residue. The square root is efficiently
   computable via [Gauss sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum#Properties) since $B$ is $N$-th root of unity modulo $n$.
2. If $N$ is 3 modulo 4, then $-N$ is quadratic residue modulo $n$
   and $N$ is quadratic non-residue. The square root is efficiently
   computable via Gauss sums since $B$ is $N$-th root of unity modulo $n$.
3. If $N$ is 1 modulo 4 and $kronecker(-N,n)=1$ then $n$ is composite
   and the kronecker symbol is efficiently computable.
   If $n$ were prime we will have $kronecker(-N,n)=legendre(-N,n)= -1$.
4. If $N$ is 3 modulo 4 and $kronecker(N,n)=1$ then $n$ is composite.

(3) and (4) can be used as compositeness checking of $n$.
If $N$ is not prime, we have algebraic factorization of $(x^N-1)/(x-1)$.

By Fermat's little theorem, (3) and (4) never happen for prime $N$.

> What properties of the factorization of $n$ can we find if
> (3) or (4) happens?

For $B=2$ the sequence of $N$ starts $15,33,39,51,55,65$